# Exclude temporary files using glob

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to exclude temporary files without writing more lines of code?

```
for file in glob.glob("C\user1\*.xlsx"):
    print(file)

C\user1\apple.xlsx
C\user1\~$apple.xlsx
```

I tried:

```
for file in glob.glob("C\user1\[^\w]*.xlsx"):
    print(file)
```

Comment: Globs are not regular expressions, they don't understand escape sequences like `\w`

Comment: Why does ```[^~]*```work in printing only temporary files?

Comment: Because `[character list]` is part of globbing syntax, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use regular expression escape sequences in globs. You also have it backwards -- you want the first character to be a word character, not exclude them.

In filename wildcards, use `[!characters]` to exclude characters, not `[^characters]`. See the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module.

```
for file in glob.glob(r"C\user1\[!~]*.xlsx"):
    print(file)
```

Comment: this seems to print only the temporary files. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Glob uses `!`, not `^`, to negate a character set.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for file in filter(lambda x: x[0] != '~', glob.glob('C\user1\*.xlsx')):
    print(file)
```